# Sufficient statistic for the mean of a generic distribution?

Tags: sufficient-statistics, umvue, rao-blackwell

Is there such thing as a "sufficient statistics for the expectation?"
From what I understand, a sufficient statistic is defined only when there is a family of distributions parametrized by $\theta$ that uniquely specifies a single distribution.

However, in a problem I am considering, I am trying to find a Rao-Blackwellization of an unbiased estimator $F(X)$ of an expectation $E f(X)$.

The problem is, I am trying to consider a nonparametric problem, and the expectation $E f(X)$ may not specify the distribution.

Is there a way to define a sufficient statistic for a quantity that does not fully determine a distribution?
Should I consider this as a case where there is an infinite dimensional nuisance parameter?
Is there an argument similar to UMVU estimators that can be applied to an estimator of a quantity that does not really determine a distribution?

(I have listed three questions that may solve my situation)

Comment: There is no useful sufficient statistic outside exponential families.

Comment: I see... I will wait for a couple more days.